# Inserting data in common fileds of layout with multiple entries in same activity

Tags: android

I have inflated one layout in my Activity now in that Activity I have some common fields for multiple times, so I have created one more layout with those common fields and included in my layout.And I got inflated all those fields.But now My problem is that While I am inserting data in those fields only first included fields gets inserted with data not the second, third, and so on... So how to get data inserted in such fields with common ids..

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View w4FragmentRowView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekly_report4_row_item, null); 
etWhere = (EditText)w4FragmentRowView.findViewById(R.id.et_weekly_reports_where_‌​w4_tab); 
etHowSubStd = (EditText)w4FragmentRowView.findViewById(R.id.et_weekly_reports_how_su‌​b_std_w4_tab);
```

Now I have to insert data multiple times in same activity with these edit Text fields.

Comment: this is how my code is:LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                View w4FragmentRowView = inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.weekly_report4_row_item,selectFragmentW4LinearLayout, false);

                etWhere = (EditText)
                        w4FragmentRowView.findViewById(R.id.et_weekly_reports_where_w4_tab);
                etHowSubStd = (EditText)
                        w4FragmentRowView.findViewById(R.id.et_weekly_reports_how_sub_std_w4_tab);

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two views and they have common ids and you inflate them
Like shown below 
now for common ids when you are doing find view by id make sure 
the point to right parent

```
//look at item and item2 as while finding view
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout1, null);
TextView skunitNameTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textView);

LinearLayout item2 = (LinearLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout1, null);
TextView skunitNameTextView2 = (TextView) item2.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

i think this should solve your problem

Comment: yeah exactly your code.But I have same same fields used multiple times in my activity now I can insert data only in first inflated fields but unable to fill data in second and thirds and so on... how to gets fill data in those remaining inflated fields with same layout

Answer (score 0):

Take example you have a layout file with name "reuse.xml" where you have only one view TextView with id "txv".

Now in your Activity you are inserting this layout file multiple times like:-

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.reuse, null);
tv1.setId(R.id.txv_activity_1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.reuse, null);
tv2.setId(R.id.txv_activity_2);
TextView tv3 = (TextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.reuse, null);
tv3.setId(R.id.txv_activity_3);
```

Now you are using the same layout file but they gave different id so you can easily update any of file which one you want.

But if you are using the same layout more than 3-4 times it is recommended to use it as ListView or RecyclerView item, which also provide you better performance in case of large layout and easy to maintain.